# Values in list of structures don't change

Tags: vb.net, foreach, structure

I have defined a structure in my code and have a list of this structures"

```
Structure Parcel
        Public name As String
        Public type As String                 
    End Structure

  Dim ParcelList As New List(Of Parcel)
```

Then I'm trying to set some values to an element of the list which name is known to me

```
For Each myParcel As Parcel In ParcelList
                If (myParcel.name = "Parcel1") Then
                    myParcel.type="Type1"
                End If
            Next
```

Unfortunately values in my list don't change at all. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

As `Parcel` is a `Structure`, it is passed by value so when iterating through collection, you are modifying a copy of your structure.

To better understand this case, you should understand what `For Each` really is. Your code can be translated into:

```
Dim enumerator As List(Of Parcel).Enumerator = ParcelList.GetEnumerator()
While enumerator.MoveNext()
    ' Here you have a local copy of your Structure
    Dim myParcel As Parcel = enumerator.Current
    Dim flag As Boolean = Operators.CompareString(myParcel.name, "Parcel1", False) = 0
    If flag Then
       ' Here you modify your local copy
       myParcel.type = "Type1"
    End If
End While
```

If `Parcel` was a `Class`, it would be passed by reference so no local copy would be created and line `myParcel.type = "Type1"` would change proper object existing in your collection.

Answer (score 1):

As already Stated this is because you are modifying a local copy of a value type. One way round this is to access the items in the list by ordinal and replace the ordinal value type with a new type:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To ParcelList.Count - 1
        If ParcelList(i).name = "Parcel1" Then
            ParcelList(i) = New Parcel With {.name = ParcelList(i).name, .type = "Type1"}
        End If
    Next
```

But really you should change the Sturcture to a Class

Answer (score -3):

When checking for strings use Equals instead of '='.

```
            If (myParcel.name.equals("Parcel1")) Then
                myParcel.type="Type1"
            End If
```

Strings are in fact 'Objects'. When you compare Strings (example StringA = StringB), you check the allocation of the String in Memory instead of the contents of the string.

Even better would be:

```
            If (myParcel.name.ToUpper().equals(Cstr("Parcel1").toUpper())) Then
                myParcel.type="Type1"
            End If
```

That way you ignore any difference case-wise.
example:
myParcel.name = "teST"

```
             myParcel.name.equals("test") 
                  is False
             myParcel.name.ToUpper().equals(Cstr("test").toUpper())
                  is true
```